# A question about properties of infinite sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, intuition

As I understand it, if a series is *absolutely convergent*, then one can legitimately rearrange terms in the series and the value of the sum will be unaffected.

This being the case, can one split a series into its even and odd components, i.e. $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2k+1}\;\;\text{?}$$ For example, can one derive the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)$ as follows: $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^{s}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{s}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\\ =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{(2n)^{s}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2n-1}}{(2n)^{s}} +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(2n-1)-1}}{(2n-1)^{s}} \\ =\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}} +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\ \Rightarrow\qquad\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$ I can't see anything wrong with what I've done, apart from the fact that I'm not quite sure whether one can legitimately split a series into its even and odd parts like this?!

Comment: Need to show that each sum converges absolutely and your good.

Comment: Do realize that this "proof" requires analytic continuation for $s<1$.  For $s>1$, absolute convergence checks in every part.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your calculations, (except maybe that you should prove that the alternate Riemann series is absolutely convergent ;-)
If $\sum u_n$ is absolutely convergent, then every sub-series is absolutely convergent (easy to prove, for example by Cauchy criterion).

Comment: @SimpleArt So one should check that both the sum of even terms and the sum of odd terms individually are absolutely convergent?! How does one analytically continue to $s<1$?

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I'm fairly new to this, how does one show that every sub series is absolutely convergent? I've read derivations of Euler's formula: $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, where one splits up the Taylor expansion of $e^{ix}$ into its even and odd components, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$ respectively.

Comment: In response to my comment, it is fairly obvious that they are all absolutely convergent.  You may see them by comparison tests.  And to analytically continue to $s<1$, you must show $\zeta(s)$ is analytic for $s>1$ and that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$ is analytic for $s>0$, and by showing that two analytic functions are equal over a domain, the smaller domain is analytically extended to the larger domain.

Comment: In response to Nic's comment, it is easy to show by using partial sums definition of an infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is a strictly rising function,
$$\sum_{k=0}^N \left|u_{\phi(k)} \right| \le \sum_{j=\phi(0)}^{\phi(N)} \left|u_{j}\right|\le \sum_{j=\phi(0)}^{\infty} \left|u_{j}\right|<+\infty$$
so every sub-series of an absolutely convergent series is absolutely convergent.

About the alternate Riemann series, it was a joke : if the "normal" series is absolutely convergent, the alternate one is also :-)

Comment: So if a given infinite series is absolutely convergent, is it always possible to rewrite it in terms of sums of its even and odd terms (since these sub-series will also be absolutely convergent)?! In the case of finite sums, how does one split them into sums of even and odd terms? Naively, I would have thought it would be something like $\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{N/2}a_{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{(N-1)/2}a_{2k+1}$, however, depending on which value of $N$ that I choose, the upper limit of one of the two sums will be non-integer, which doesn't make sense?!

Comment: Take integer parts of your boundaries. $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$, the largest integer lower than $N/2$.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise that there is notation for this. Is $\lfloor x\rfloor$ simply the so-called *floor* function, i.e. $\lfloor x\rfloor=\text{max}\lbrace m\in\mathbb{Z}\vert\;m\leq x\rbrace$?!